# Solving an overdetermined set of equations with lsqcurvefit in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, nonlinear-optimization

I have a problem similar to this question:
[How to solve an overdetermined set of equations using non-linear lest squares in Matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24382626/how-to-solve-an-overdetermined-set-of-equations-using-non-linear-lest-squares-in)

I have 9 equations with 2 unknowns x and y, as follows:

```
A11=(sin(x))*(cos(y))*(sin(x))*(cos(y));
A12=(sin(x))*(cos(y))*(sin(x))*(sin(y));
A13=(sin(x))*(cos(y))*(cos(x));
A21=(sin(x))*(sin(y))*(sin(x))*(cos(y));
A22=(sin(x))*(sin(y))*(sin(x))*(sin(y));
A23=(sin(x))*(sin(y))*(cos(x));
A31=(sin(x))*(cos(y))*(cos(x));
A32=(sin(x))*(sin(y))*(cos(x));
A33=(cos(x))*(cos(x));
```

I know the values for each A_ij and want to calculate x and y.
I tried to realize that by using lsqcurvefit like this:

```
ydata=[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]; % this is one set of A_ij
lb=[0,0];
ub=[pi,2*pi];
x0=[pi/2;pi];
p=zeros(2,1);
p = lsqcurvefit( myfun,x0,xdata,ydata,lb,ub)
```

I don't have any values for xdata, so is there any way to still make it run like this?
I defined the function myfun as:

```
function r = myfun(p)

x=p(1);
y=p(2);

The 9 equations;

r=[A11, A12, A13, A21, A22, A23, A31, A32, A33];
end
```

Now, whenever I run lsqcurvefit I get the error "Not enough input arguments." And the error occurs in the line of x=p(1);
I don't know what is missing or better, I don't know how to handle the fact that I don't have xdata input.

I hope somebody can help me getting this to work.
Thank you very much in advance.

Fabian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some tinkering I got it to work with lsqcurvefit. It was basically a problem of how I addressed the xdata and ydata to the function handle.
This is how my code looked like in the end:

```
ydata = [0.12; 0.28; 0.16; 0.66; 0.38; 0.22];
xdata = [0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0]; % just as a dummy, lsqcurvefit wants the input
x0=[0,0];
lb=[0,0];
ub=[180,180];
[x,resnorm,residual,exitflag,output] = lsqcurvefit(@fun,x0,xdata,ydata,lb,ub);
% only x is needed, but I used the other information for other parts of my code
% as a separate function.m file
function F = fun(x,xdata) % again, xdata is just a dummy and not used

p1=cosd(x(1));
p2=sind(x(1))*sind(x(2));
p3=sind(x(1))*cosd(x(2));
% I didn't need all 9 entries, since the 3x3 matrix is symmetric
F =[p1*p1;...
    p1*p2;...
    p1*p3;...
    p2*p2;...
    p2*p3;...
    p3*p3];

end
```

I hope, somebody gets use from this information.